# Jekyll Grouping and Sorting Collection by Category and Priority

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a bunch of documentation pages in a collection, which all have a Category, which I am using a `group_by` filter on like so:

```
{% assign docs_by_category = site.documentation | group_by: "category" %}
```

Then I use these groupings to create a menu structure, where items for each category are listed under a header. This is all good.

However, my problem lies in, being able to sort, which category is shown first, so I would like to be able to somehow prioritize them.

Say, if I have a the following categories: `tutorials, getting started, advanced`. I wouldn't want `advanced` to show up as the first category, but rather `getting started`.

The current code for generating the menu looks something like:

```
{% assign navurl = page.url | remove: 'index.html' %}
{% assign docs_by_category = site.documentation | group_by: "category" | reverse %}

{% for category in docs_by_category %}
  <div class="category_wrapper">
    <div class="category">{{ category.name }}</div>
    <ul>
    {% for item in category.items %}
      <li class="collapsed">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">
          {% if item.url == navurl %}
            <u>{{ item.title }}</u>
          {% else %}
            {{ item.title }}
          {% endif %}
          </a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

TL;DR: How do I sort groups by some kind of priority?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a configuration array to store categories order :

```
# _config.yml
categories-order:
 - getting started
 - tutorials
 - advanced
```

Then :

```
{% assign docs_by_category = site.documentation | group_by: "category" %}
{% for cat in site.categories-order %}
  {% assign currentCat = docs_by_category | where: 'name', cat | first %}
  <div class="category_wrapper">
    <div class="category">{{ currentCat.name }}</div>
    <ul>
    {% for item in currentCat.items %}
      <li class="collapsed">
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">
        {% if item.url == navurl %}
          <u>{{ item.title }}</u>
        {% else %}
          {{ item.title }}
        {% endif %}
        </a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This implies that you reference all you categories in you config, otherwise, they will not appear in this listing.

Comment: Thanks David, I will have a look at this and see how it works. I guess this could somehow be modified into first iterating groups that have a priority, then take the rest in the order they come in. Probably needs two loops, but I think it is doable.